# Solving a nonlinear system of equations in Julia

Tags: julia

I can write in function in Matlab in this way:

```
function res=resid(theta,alpha,beta); 
RHS=[];
LHS=[];
RHS= theta-alpha;
LHS= theta*beta;
res = (LHS-RHS);
```

We set the parameters, call the function:

```
alpha=0.3;beta=0.95;
a01=[1.0;1.0];
th=fsolve('resid',a01,[],alpha,beta)
```

This will return [6.0;6.0]. Does the option"[]" signal to fsolve that the input is a vector?

Anyway, how can I implement this in Julia using a NLsolve, Optim or JuMP? The original problem has more than 10 variables, so I would prefer a vector approach.

I can implement the function in Julia:

```
h! =function (theta) 
RHS=[];
LHS=[];
RHS= theta-alpha;
LHS= theta*beta;
res= (LHS-RHS); 
return res;
end
```

But simply using NLsolve:

```
a01 = [1.0;1.0];
res = nlsolve(h!,a01)
```

Returns:

```
MethodError: no method matching (::##17#18)(::Array{Float64,1}, ::Array{Float64,1})
Closest candidates are:
  #17(::Any) at In[23]:3
```

If I alternatively use Optim, I get:

```
using Optim
optimize(h!, a01)
```

which returns:

```
MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Array{Float64,1} to an object of type Float64
This may have arisen from a call to the constructor Float64(...),
since type constructors fall back to convert methods.
```

Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: Could you state what parts of e.g. the documentation of NLsolve you've looked at, and what in particular is causing you problems?

Comment: There is an update!

Comment: Did you look at the NLsolve.jl documentation? That's not how you define the function. If your function is not in place, you use `nlsolve(not_in_place(f), initial_x)`. But why not just use the inplace version from the documentation? `function f!(x, fvec)` first vector is input second is output?

Comment: Thanks! not_in_place(f) would do it. I just needed to keep the odd definition of the function!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the suggestion by Chris Rackauckas, the solution would be to keep the definition of h:

```
h =function (theta) 
RHS=[];
LHS=[];
RHS= theta-alpha;
LHS= theta*beta;
res= (LHS-RHS); 
return res;
end
```

and to use not_in_place:

```
a01 = [1.0;1.0];
solve = nlsolve(not_in_place(h),a01)
```

Returning a solution:

```
Results of Nonlinear Solver Algorithm
 * Algorithm: Trust-region with dogleg and autoscaling
 * Starting Point: [1.0,1.0]
 * Zero: [6.0,6.0]
 * Inf-norm of residuals: 0.000000
 * Iterations: 3
 * Convergence: true
   * |x - x'| < 0.0e+00: false
   * |f(x)| < 1.0e-08: true
 * Function Calls (f): 4
 * Jacobian Calls (df/dx): 4
```

Thank you!

Comment: As a matter of convention, you should not call the function `h!` if it's not a mutating function. See [this page in the docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/style-guide/#Append-!-to-names-of-functions-that-modify-their-arguments-1). Also, you should mark this as the solution so that way other SO users can see that it's been solved.

Comment: Ok! But since I wrote an answer myself, I will be able to mark it in 48 hours. But I will do it...